# Problem with PettingZoo and Stable-Baselines3 with a ParallelEnv

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines, multi-agent-reinforcement-learning, pettingzoo

I am having trouble in making things work with a Custom `ParallelEnv` I wrote by using [PettingZoo](https://www.pettingzoo.ml/). I am using [SuperSuit](https://github.com/Farama-Foundation/SuperSuit)'s `ss.pettingzoo_env_to_vec_env_v1(env)` as a wrapper to Vectorize the environment and make it work with [Stable-Baseline3](https://github.com/DLR-RM/stable-baselines3) and documented [here](https://github.com/Farama-Foundation/SuperSuit#parallel-environment-vectorization).

You can find attached a summary of the most relevant part of the code:

```py
from typing import Optional
from gym import spaces
import random
import numpy as np
from pettingzoo import ParallelEnv
from pettingzoo.utils.conversions import parallel_wrapper_fn
import supersuit as ss
from gym.utils import EzPickle, seeding


def env(**kwargs):
    env_ = parallel_env(**kwargs)
    env_ = ss.pettingzoo_env_to_vec_env_v1(env_)
    #env_ = ss.concat_vec_envs_v1(env_, 1)
    return env_


petting_zoo = env


class parallel_env(ParallelEnv, EzPickle):
    metadata = {'render_modes': ['ansi'], "name": "PlayerEnv-Multi-v0"}

    def __init__(self, n_agents: int = 20, new_step_api: bool = True) -> None:
        EzPickle.__init__(
            self,
            n_agents,
            new_step_api
        )

        self._episode_ended = False
        self.n_agents = n_agents

        self.possible_agents = [
            f"player_{idx}" for idx in range(n_agents)]

        self.agents = self.possible_agents[:]

        self.agent_name_mapping = dict(
            zip(self.possible_agents, list(range(len(self.possible_agents))))
        )

        self.observation_spaces = spaces.Dict(
            {agent: spaces.Box(shape=(len(self.agents),),
                               dtype=np.float64, low=0.0, high=1.0) for agent in self.possible_agents}
        )

        self.action_spaces = spaces.Dict(
            {agent: spaces.Discrete(4) for agent in self.possible_agents}
        )
        self.current_step = 0

    def seed(self, seed=None):
        self.np_random, seed = seeding.np_random(seed)

    def observation_space(self, agent):
        return self.observation_spaces[agent]

    def action_space(self, agent):
        return self.action_spaces[agent]

    def __calculate_observation(self, agent_id: int) -> np.ndarray:
        return self.observation_space(agent_id).sample()

    def __calculate_observations(self) -> np.ndarray:
        observations = {
            agent: self.__calculate_observation(
                agent_id=agent)
            for agent in self.agents
        }
        return observations

    def observe(self, agent):
        return self.__calculate_observation(agent_id=agent)

    def step(self, actions):
        if self._episode_ended:
            return self.reset()
        observations = self.__calculate_observations()
        rewards = random.sample(range(100), self.n_agents)
        self.current_step += 1
        self._episode_ended = self.current_step >= 100
        infos = {agent: {} for agent in self.agents}
        dones = {agent: self._episode_ended for agent in self.agents}
        rewards = {
            self.agents[i]: rewards[i]
            for i in range(len(self.agents))
        }
        if self._episode_ended:
            self.agents = {}  # To satisfy `set(par_env.agents) == live_agents`
        return observations, rewards, dones, infos

    def reset(self,
              seed: Optional[int] = None,
              return_info: bool = False,
              options: Optional[dict] = None,):
        self.agents = self.possible_agents[:]
        self._episode_ended = False
        self.current_step = 0
        observations = self.__calculate_observations()
        return observations

    def render(self, mode="human"):
        # TODO: IMPLEMENT
        print("TO BE IMPLEMENTED")

    def close(self):
        pass
```

Unfortunately when I try to test with the following main procedure:

```py
from stable_baselines3 import DQN, PPO
from stable_baselines3.common.env_checker import check_env
from dummy_env import dummy
from pettingzoo.test import parallel_api_test


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Testing the parallel algorithm alone
    env_parallel = dummy.parallel_env()
    parallel_api_test(env_parallel)  # This works!

    # Testing the environment with the wrapper
    env = dummy.petting_zoo()

    # ERROR: AssertionError: The observation returned by the `reset()` method does not match the given observation space 
    check_env(env)  

    # Model initialization
    model = PPO("MlpPolicy", env, verbose=1)
    
    # ERROR: ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (20,20) into shape (20,)
    model.learn(total_timesteps=10_000)
```

I get the following error:

```
AssertionError: The observation returned by the `reset()` method does not match the given observation space
```

If I skip `check_env()` I get the following one:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (20,20) into shape (20,)
```

It seems like that `ss.pettingzoo_env_to_vec_env_v1(env)` is capable of splitting the parallel environment in multiple vectorized ones, but not for the `reset()` function.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Plese find the [Github Repository](https://github.com/PieroMacaluso/dummy-env) to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Your observation's shape and observation's low shape is different. How is it working for you? I'm getting error if I use similar code with pettingzoo's check_parallel_env api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to discussion I had in the [issue section of the SuperSuit repository](https://github.com/Farama-Foundation/SuperSuit/issues/169), I am able to post the solution to the problem. Thanks to [jjshoots](https://github.com/jjshoots)!

First of all it is necessary to have the latest `SuperSuit` version. In order to get that I needed to install `Stable-Baseline3` using the instructions [here](https://stable-baselines3.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/install.html#bleeding-edge-version) to make it work with `gym 0.24+`.

After that, taking the code in the question as example, it is necessary to substitute

```py
def env(**kwargs):
    env_ = parallel_env(**kwargs)
    env_ = ss.pettingzoo_env_to_vec_env_v1(env_)
    #env_ = ss.concat_vec_envs_v1(env_, 1)
    return env_
```

with

```py
def env(**kwargs):
    env_ = parallel_env(**kwargs)
    env_ = ss.pettingzoo_env_to_vec_env_v1(env_)
    env_ = ss.concat_vec_envs_v1(env_, 1, base_class="stable_baselines3")
    return env_
```

The outcomes are:

- **Outcome 1**: leaving the line with `check_env(env)` I got an error `AssertionError: Your environment must inherit from the gym.Env class cf https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/core.py`
- **Outcome 2**: removing the line with `check_env(env)`, the agent starts training successfully!

In the end, I think that the argument `base_class="stable_baselines3"` made the difference.
Only the small problem on `check_env` remains to be reported, but I think it can be considered as trivial if the training works.

Answer (score 0):

You should double check the reset() function in PettingZoo. It will return None instead of an observation like  GYM

Comment: It is a `ParallelEnv`, therefore `reset()` function must return an observation object as reported in the documentation [here](https://www.pettingzoo.ml/environment_creation#example-custom-parallel-environment). Is it right?